# Is there a way to make ts-jest treat warnings as errors?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm fixing some Jest configuration warnings that show up in our repo, for example:

```
ts-jest[ts-jest-transformer] (WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated...
```

```
ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should...
```

After I fix these, I'd like to prevent someone accidentally introducing them (or other warnings) again. Is there a way to configure ts-jest such that configuration warnings show up as failures and cause the `jest` command to fail?

Comment: Those messages are created directly by `ts-jest`, through its [own logger](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/9f1439a97588ddfb32abb75003041835877fc910/src/utils/logger.ts) - Jest never sees them.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the original post to specify that I'm looking to make ts-jest treat them as errors and fail the jest command.